# Change speed of rotation (magnitude) without changing direction (sign)

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I have this code that rotates my object:

```
      private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log(Speed);
        }
```

When I call this function, I want the object to start rotating in the opposite direction (this works):

```
        public void changeDir()
        {
            Speed = -Speed;
        }
```

When I call these functions, I want to change the speed of rotation, while keeping the direction (clockwise or counterclockwise) the same. But these always make the object rotate to the right instead of left:

```
        public void ZoomSpeed()
        {
            Speed = 330f;
        }
    
        public void ZoomNormal()
        {
            Speed = 125f;
    }
```

How do I maintain the same direction (sign) when changing the rotation speed?

Comment: Could you show us, from where you are calling `changeDir()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you might be looking for something like this?

```
public void ZoomSpeed()
{
    Speed = 330f * Mathf.Sign(Speed);
}

public void ZoomNormal()
{
    Speed = 125f * Mathf.Sign(Speed);
}
```

That is, you want to change the magnitude of the `Speed` variable, while keeping its sign? (So if `Speed` was less than zero before calling `ZoomSpeed()`, it will be -300 afterward, instead of +300?)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!